# Why is it a bad idea to pipe wget or curl to shell?

Tags: shell, curl, sh, wget

Can someone explain why it is a bad idea to pipe wget or curl to shell?

Also, are there any other Unix/Linux commands that are unsafe to be piped to shell?

Answer (score 3):

This will probably be closed since it belongs on SuperUser instead, but roughly speaking the problem with executing scripts remotely from a site is that you don't actually know what the content of the script is doing, so it might do something malicious like `rm -rf` intentionally or otherwise.

It's better to download the script, inspect it for such mistakes or errors, and then execute it when you've satisfied yourself that it doesn't contain errors that may either break your system or install malicious software.

This applies to executing any script in any shell (`sh`, `zsh` etc.) and isn't specific to `bash` scripts.